# Getting rid of google maps built-in buttons

Tags: android, google-maps

Anyone have any idea on how to get rid of the buttons (like the compass button when rotating the map) presented on the image when clicking a marker. It is linked to Google map application. And i want to get rid of it. thanks

Here is the link for the sample image   https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gw5b.png

Comment: Read This https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/i8cP4ko6Bgc

Comment: thanks mate, I have found the answer by using the link that you provided.